# Issues with files naming when useing filerev & usemin

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, grunt-usemin

Lets assume I have 2 static assets (html files) in my project, files `a.html` and `b.html`.
File `a.html` has a link to file `b.html` inside of it.

Now I run a build and the 2 files got their name changed and everything is working fine (by the filerev module).
Now I need to make a small change only in file `b.html` -> filerev will give a new name to file `b.html` in the next build. Because file a was not changed it will have the same name as the prev build.

Now, in the next build usemin will go to file a and will fix the link to the new `file b` name and everything looks fine. But not, because file a still has the same name as prev build, users will get a broken link when trying to access file b from a.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a workaround is to instead of having hashes of the file names, generate random file names each time.
That way you are generating all files so it is not optimized, but you prevent the caching problems between versions, while still allow caching of the browser for the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the grunt-angular-template task can solve this issue as it is adding all the templates to the $templateCache of angular, so the no real requests will be made to the server when a template is requested and the recent template is loaded from the cache. Of course it is not ideal as in big applications you will not want this as this may increase your js file size